# iOS 7.1: Why does my custom UITableViewController inside UINavigationController inside WEPopoverController not appear?

Tags: ios, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uitableview

I have a view controller hierarchy.

```
WEPopoverViewController
  UINavigationController
    CustomUITableViewController
```

The UITableView of the CustomUITableViewController does not appear, the PopOver is shown, but empty. viewDidLoad of CustomUITableViewController is called, but viewWillAppear:animated and viewDidAppear:animated are not called.

Here is the code for setting up the hierarchy:

```
    CustomUITableViewController* browser = [[CustomUITableViewController alloc] init];
    browser.delegate = self;
    browser.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(650, 750);
    browser.title = NSLocalizedString(@"FileImportBrowserTitle", nil);
    UINavigationController* nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:browser];
    nc.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(700, 900);
    nc.delegate = self;
    WEPopoverController *poc = [[WEPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:nc];
    browser.parentPopover = poc;    
    [poc presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:self.browseButton permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp  animated:YES];
```

Any hints are welcome.

Comment: Have you tried to change UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp in UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny and see if popover shows up?

Comment: Empty popover also shows with UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny.